# what is tool for actionscript development in image processing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, image-processing, actionscript, flash-builder

i am building a image processing web application. i am new to Action Script. I am confused whether to use Adobe Flash Professional or Adobe Flash Builder. I have surfed a lot, but unable to conclude anything.
Also please suggest me some good tutorials regarding action script.
It will be very grateful.

Comment: With its extended highly customizable components, FB and Flex SDK would be the number one choice for that kind of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pretty much any kind of image manipulation you want to via Flash Builder and the Apache Flex SDK. I do a lot of this type of work. You can manipulate pixels however you want in ActionScript. You can also perform neat tricks for storing the pixel data. For instance, I make videos from sprites and from things people draw on the stage. To conserve space in the final constructed sprites, I am able to do things like this:

```
        var bitmap:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;          
        var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        byteArray.writeUnsignedInt(bitmapData.width);
        bitmapData.copyPixelsToByteArray(bitmapData.rect, byteArray);
        byteArray.compress();
```

BTW, if you want to save these images locally, use a FileStream and the File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath() function.

Then, when you need to get your compressed bytes back into an image, you can do this:

```
        var bytes:ByteArray = bytesFromStoredByteArray;
        bytes.uncompress();             
        var width:int = bytes.readUnsignedInt();
        var height:int = ((bytes.length - 4) / 4) / width;              
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true);
        bitmapData.setPixels(bitmapData.rect, bytes);
```

There are many methods in the API for manipulating pixels. You can pretty much do anything you want to do with Flash Builder and the Apache Flex SDK.

When I first learned, I used the Flex in a Week program that Adobe supports. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html

However, while Flex in a Week will teach you about Flex, I personally don't recommend you use Flex too often. I use Flex in a very limited context and use ActionScript anywhere and everywhere I can. I never used any tutorials to learn ActionScript. Instead, I just looked at the API whenever I needed to know something and since the programming conventions are very similar to Java - which I already knew well - it was fairly easy for me to get up to speed with ActionScript. If you have not worked with an asynchronous language before, however, I would recommend you learn about the event model in ActionScript and know that you must use it. You should never just run a loop and expect your program to produce what you think it should produce. Use Flex for most UI components you want to render and ActionScript for any programming logic you need to implement.

Another bit of trouble to look out for is that often times in AS you can use the event model and still cause your program to crash. So, if you have a large set of images to decompress or manipulate in some way, put in Timers to keep your program from freezing. If I have a lot of work scheduled for my app to do, I will allow relevant part of the program to to run for 20 MS and then time it out for 50 MS. By doing this, the rest of the app stays usable and people's systems don't crash.

Good luck. If you have specific questions about image processing, manipulation or ActionScript, I'm happy to help.